# Finding specific word strings within a pandas column using if/else statements

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I'm trying to label a 'description' column based on the strings within it. I am using an if/else statement for this.

Right now it looks like this:

```
def char_matching(chars):
   if 'software' in chars:
       return 'Software development'
   elif 'Data' in chars:
       return 'Data Science'`
```

But what if I want to find the words 'data science' together in a column do I write:

```
elif 'Data-science' in chars:
    return 'Data Science'`
```

or

```
elif 'Data|science' in chars:
    return 'Data Science' `
```

And does this apply to caps lock i.e. 'data' and 'Data'. How do you get over that hurdle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings in your `if` / `else` construct may contain spaces.

This will `return` "Data Science" if "data science" (case insensitive) occurs anywhere in your string variable.

To deal with case insensitivity compare versus `chars.lower()`. If you do not make this change, then case sensitivity will apply.

```
def char_matching(chars):
   val = chars.lower()
   if 'software' in val:
       return 'Software development'
   elif 'data science' in val:
       return 'Data Science'
   ...
```

To test for multiple words, you can use `and`:

```
def char_matching(chars):
   val = chars.lower()
   if 'software' in val:
       return 'Software development'
   elif ('data' in val) and ('science' in val):
       return 'Data Science'
   ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the input - but doesn't that mean it will look for 'data' individually in the column and 'science' individually... so the description could say for example: 'This is a medical science role where there is a considerable amount of data administration'. And then it labels that as Data Science. Will this be the case?

Comment: Yep! So just a spacing is required?

Comment: is it possible if you could put up your previous answer as another elif please, that would be useful to know how to use and as well. Thanks